# Creating a view as shown in Picture for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview

I am creating an app where I need to show the data in this format[image: Data representation]

Now, this is inside a UITableView, let's say its a UITableViewCell.

What I am thinking of doing:-

```
1. Lets create a UICollectionView inside the UITableViewCell, this will have 
   3 rows. Every row will contain another UICollectionView where I will put 
   the data
   FLow will be like this :-
   UITableView -> UITableViewCell -> UICollectionView -> UICollectionViewCell -> UICollectionView -> UICollectionViewCell

2. create a UICollectionView inside the UITableViewCell, this will have 
       3 rows. Now I will create a view which contains data as whole and put it on cell. Height will be calculated programatically and view is put inside UICollectionViewCell
```

So other solutions are like that but I am not satisfied with the solutions I am getting in my mind.

If anyone knows a proper solution to do this. Let me know. Doing in a better way is what I prefer.

Do let me know if you need more details on this

Comment: if the data is going to be related, like name and age, then you can manage it in a single uitableview cell. Name and Age, will be two different labels in a section header, other details will be simple uitableviewcell.

Comment: No, It is not related.

Comment: Why do you need to keep the UITableView?
You could replace the tableView with a CollectionView entirely.
You can then write a layout for this specific cell so that it is rendered as a grid. and you can render the other cells as full width cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this in a hacky way.

This is a UITableViewCell in a UITableView, put UICollectionView inside this cell and have 3 UICollectionViewCell.

Logic to create UICollectionViewCell to look the way it is looking in the picture.

> ```
> 1. Use label1 and make it look like the header.
> 2. for all the subData make a label, make it multiline and when we are passing the data in the label append newLine to every single word.
>
> Label1.text -> "Skill"
> Label2.text = "Swimming\n Running\n surfing\n athletic"
> ```

Now we can get the height of the labels which would become the height of UICollectionViewCell.
I found this the easiest way to do this type of screen.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `UICollectionView`
Add `UICollectionViewCell` to the view in storyboard
Add a `Vertical UIStackView` to the cell with attributes `Fill, and Equal Spacing`.
Add Layout Constraints to `top,left,right,bottom` to the Cell.

now inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function you can add as many `addArrangedSubviews` to the `UIStackView`.

To customize the size of `Cell` override function `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`